# Redefine DELIMITER in MySQL script not supported in SSIS client

Tags: ssis

I want to create procedure for importing into Mysql Database.
If I run the following query in the SQL executor task, it fails.

```
DELIMITER $$

create procedure abc

as

begin

select count(*) from tableA;

select count(*) from tableB;

end

DELIMITER ;
```

Which shows there is a problem with the DELIMITER command.
I checked if the problem is with the .NET connector for MYSQL. But as per the forums in Mysql, it has been resolved there:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-news-6-3-1.html

Mysql connector bug for this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46429

Actually DELIMITER is client side command, so I came to the conclusion that the problem is with SSIS.

COULD somebody please put some light on this?

Comment: Just a question, but why are you creating a procedure in a sql exec task in an SSIS package?  Wouldn't you create the stored proc in the mysql side and execute it from SSIS unless you are trying to do something dynamic with the SSIS?

Comment: You didn't say what "failed" means, did you get the same error referenced in the Connector documentation? And although I know nothing about MySQL, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) suggests that you should close the procedure with your custom delimiter before resetting it, i.e. you should have `$$$` a second time, after `end`. But as William asked, why are you creating procedures during package execution? That's quite an unusual approach.